# HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Again stucked with tweepy.

I got an app that uses tweepy oauth authentication and follows step by step the instructions from the tutorial:

http://joshthecoder.github.com/tweepy/docs/auth_tutorial.html#oauth-authentication

This app was working correctly, but now, is only returning the same exception in any user attempt to authenticate, even with new accounts.

I have spent a few hours on this and I can't get a solution.

Any idea?

```
HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
Request Method: GET 
Request URL: http://(hidden)/?oauth_token=FSL76eId7n64I1ACX1EKBHIV504xlZmQjJg8iO3Bc&oauth_verifier=KVjaxpzFn40JCXvk4r5cDNVbdILaiuF5szv6yBcpQo 
Django Version: 1.2.1 
Exception Type: TweepError 
Exception Value: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Exception Location: /(hidden)/tweepy/auth.py in get_access_token, line 126 
Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/python 
Python Version: 2.6.5
```

Answer (score 0):

One guess may be the accounts are blocked try using cURL to figure out if you are blacklisted, in which case Twitter probably won't have notified you of this. Alternatively, try another module: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries

for cURL do the following:

```
curl  -i -u  my_account:fuuu! http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json -v
```

Where my_account is your Twitter account. Hope that helps.